# True or false? Suppose that S⊂ℝ and (1) 1 ∈S and (2) if k ∈S, then (k+1)∈S. Then S=ℕ.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

True or false?

Suppose that S ⊂ ℝ and (1) 1 ∈S and (2) if k ∈ S, then (k+1)∈ S. Then S = ℕ.

I would say False, because S is any inductive subset of ℝ then ℕ ⊂ S.

I am not sure if my answer is correct but if so how can I show this with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument should be improved. After all, perhaps the only inductive subset of $\mathbb R$ is $\mathbb N$, in which case the claim would be true. Instead of what you wrote just exhibit one subset of $\mathbb R$ which is inductive, but is not equal to $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Take $S = \mathbb{Q}$, the rationals.

Answer (score 0):

A counterexample is a counterexample, but rather than $S=\mathbb{Q}$, I would have chosen $S=\mathbb{R}$.  This illuminates the fact that the required properties do nothing to keep $S$ from being all of $\mathbb{R}$.